# How use nested enum of one class as a nested enum of another?

Tags: c++, enums

The code bellow will give compile error on line `enum en = A::en;` but it describes what I want to do (to make nested enum of `A` to be nested enum of `B` as well).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    enum a_en{X = 0, Y = 1};
};
struct B
{
    enum b_en = A::a_en; //syntax error
};
int main()
{
    cout << B::X << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is how can I do such thing in c++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the enum in a base class that both A and B can inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
struct B: A
{
};
```

instead of

```
struct B
{
    enum b_en = A::a_en;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When the classes/structs are related this way, you should inherit them. Put the public enum in base class so that all derived (related) classes can access it.

MFC' `CFile` class has enums defined, which `CStdioFile` and other derived classes can use:

```
enum OpenFlags {
        modeRead =         (int) 0x00000,
        modeWrite =        (int) 0x00001,
...    };
```